# HELP Please WIFI I just need a question

Tags: wifi

Basically I am trying to make a Wifi Receiving Boost of Some sort but Lack the knowledge on some things.

This is a couple ideas I've had....

Strip the wire down on a usb cord and connect the Positive and negative D to ports on a TV antenna but I am concerned it may not work due to the Vbus and GND or If I Can Connect the Vbus and Gnd were would they go and would it fry my computer?

Another question I guess would be if I were to make a biquad out of copper could I just use that with some configuration on the wires I think manly the D+ D- but I might be wrong and could it be possible to some how connect a end from a coaxe to a usb port?

Comment: Wow. You really, really need to do some basic research about how radio waves work, as well as how electrical signaling (such as USB) work. You're way, way **WAY** off-base about how you think these things work.

Answer (score 4):

As a very simplified explanation of why you're off-base with how things work:

USB is a digital interface designed for use with a cable to connect perhiperals to a host. Even a small break in the cable will cause it to stop operating, it has no in-built wireless capability.

A WiFi dongle / adapter has a USB interface connected to a WiFi transceiver that handles the wireless communications side of things. Despite their small size they are really quite complex because both USB and WiFi are both quite involved protocols.

The simple answer for what you're trying to do is to purchase a USB to WiFi adapter with an external antenna connection. A quick search on e-bay for "usb wifi external antenna" for example returned many devices under $10.